# Vlookup Certain Criteria From One Workbook to Another

Tags: vba, excel

I have been racking my brain on this because I suck with excel. I have two workbooks. One workbook (survey workbook) contains a column of specific numbers that I need to find in another workbook(ticket workbook). The ticket workbook is a massive dataset with multiple columns that serve no use to me. What I need from the ticket workbook are two columns. The numbers I  am searching for have a column associated with them that I need to pull too. So I need to search for these exact numbers within the ticket workbook and return those numbers along with the one associated column I need. I would like to automate this process with VBA if possible.

I have used ctrl+shift+end to select the entire table and I named it data.

I created two additional columns in the ticket workbook labeled ticket (with the numbers that I need under the header) and driver (for the other column I need in the workbook).

Here is my code : 
=VLOOKUP(Q5,data,12,FALSE)

Q5 contains the first number that I'm trying to find within the workbook. 12 is the column that I need associated with the number I'm searching for in the workbook.The formula cames back as #N/A.

I'm tried using the index and match function , but I'm still getting #N/A.

My Code: 
=INDEX(Tick_Nums,MATCH($A2,Tick_Drivs,0),COLUMNS('Report 1'!C5))

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the help page, including [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also Note that SO is NOT a code writing service...we are programmers trying to help other programmers through specific questions or errors. If you don't include the code you are working with and a detailed explanation of any errors or expectations vs reality...we can't help much.  Use code formatted in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The workbook, "Report 1", must be open.  For that matter, if `Tick_Nums` is only one column, you shouldn't need the `COLUMNS('Report 1'!C5)`.  _This would be much easier to diagnose with a screenshot of some of these columns..._

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Rdster's comment.  That said, you don't need VBA.  You're looking for `MATCH` and `INDEX`.  You just want to `MATCH` the *number* in the ticket workbook and use that output as input to the `INDEX` for each column of data you want.  Good luck and edit your post if you have issues (but please provide some failed formulas next time).

Comment: For `VLOOKUP`, the value in `Q5` _must_ be found in the left most column.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who took the time to provide help.  I figured it out with this code:

```
=VLOOKUP(A15,'Report 1'!C:M,11,FALSE)
```

The key here though was to **convert those numbers from text to numbers**.  Excel did not recognize them as numbers at first, but once I did that it worked.